# How to write delta s i j in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I write this,

```
from sympy import *
deltas = symbols('Delta_s_i_j')
```

it gives me all three `s`, `i`, and `j` in the subscript.

I want only `i` and `j` in the subscript.
`Delta` and `s` should be in the same height

Comment: I want the delta symbol, which comes with `Delta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> Symbol('\Delta{s}_{ij}')
```

[image]